# How to integrate Capacitorjs with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, webpack, capacitor

The web app is already written in node.js but the project pivoted to a mobile app platform, capacitor is promising way to easily run a node.js web app to a native mobile. However after doing some research, most of the projects and examples are coming from a client side rendered apps i.e. react.js apps, vue.js apps, etc. I'm thinking Webpack will be useful since you can easily make static files for Capacitorjs's webDir to be pointed to, but any thoughts on this? i'm all ears for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't i suggest you use nodejs as a back-end and use react.js as front-end by then you can use capacitor.js and point webDir to the static files of react.js app